# Problem with LWA Token Exchange using Selling-Partner Java SDK

Tags: java, amazon-mws, amazon-marketplace

My code

```
AWSAuthenticationCredentials awsAuthenticationCredentials = AWSAuthenticationCredentials.builder()
                .accessKeyId("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX").secretKey("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
                .region("eu-west-1").build();
        
        AWSAuthenticationCredentialsProvider awsAuthenticationCredentialsProvider = AWSAuthenticationCredentialsProvider
                .builder().roleArn("XXXXXXXXXXXXX").roleSessionName("123123123")
                .build();



        LWAAuthorizationCredentials lwaAuthorizationCredentials = LWAAuthorizationCredentials.builder()
                .clientId("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
                .clientSecret("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
                .endpoint("https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token").build();


        SellersApi sellersApi = new SellersApi.Builder().awsAuthenticationCredentials(awsAuthenticationCredentials)
                .lwaAuthorizationCredentials(lwaAuthorizationCredentials)
                .awsAuthenticationCredentialsProvider(awsAuthenticationCredentialsProvider)
                .endpoint("https://sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com").build();

        GetMarketplaceParticipationsResponse res = sellersApi.getMarketplaceParticipations();
        List<MarketplaceParticipation> data = new ArrayList<MarketplaceParticipation>();
        data = res.getPayload();
        for (MarketplaceParticipation obj : data) {
            System.out.println(obj);
        }
```

Error:

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error getting LWA Access Token
at com.amazon.SellingPartnerAPIAA.LWAClient.getAccessTokenFromEndpoint(LWAClient.java:74)
at com.amazon.SellingPartnerAPIAA.LWAClient.getAccessTokenFromCache(LWAClient.java:51)
at com.amazon.SellingPartnerAPIAA.LWAClient.getAccessToken(LWAClient.java:40)
at com.amazon.SellingPartnerAPIAA.LWAAuthorizationSigner.sign(LWAAuthorizationSigner.java:69)
at com.amazon.sellingpartner.ApiClient.buildRequest(ApiClient.java:1034)
at com.amazon.sellingpartner.ApiClient.buildCall(ApiClient.java:973)
at com.amazon.sellingpartner.api.SellersApi.getMarketplaceParticipationsCall(SellersApi.java:111)
at com.amazon.sellingpartner.api.SellersApi.getMarketplaceParticipationsValidateBeforeCall(SellersApi.java:118)
at com.amazon.sellingpartner.api.SellersApi.getMarketplaceParticipationsWithHttpInfo(SellersApi.java:141)
at com.amazon.sellingpartner.api.SellersApi.getMarketplaceParticipations(SellersApi.java:130)
at com.yash.spapi.TestSpApiApplication.main(TestSpApiApplication.java:47)
... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unsuccessful LWA token exchange
at com.amazon.SellingPartnerAPIAA.LWAClient.getAccessTokenFromEndpoint(LWAClient.java:63)
... 15 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem not to have provided the refresh token when constructing the `LWAAuthorizationCredentials`. Try inserting `.refreshToken("<your-refresh-token>")` after `.clientSecret("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")`.

The following code works for me (with self authorization, and correct security parameters of course):

```
package amzspapitest;

import com.amazon.SellingPartnerAPIAA.AWSAuthenticationCredentials;
import com.amazon.SellingPartnerAPIAA.AWSAuthenticationCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazon.SellingPartnerAPIAA.LWAAuthorizationCredentials;
import io.swagger.client.ApiException;
import io.swagger.client.api.SellersApi;
import io.swagger.client.model.GetMarketplaceParticipationsResponse;
import io.swagger.client.model.MarketplaceParticipation;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

public class AmzSPAPITest {
    protected final String awsAccessKeyId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    protected final String awsSecretAccessKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    protected final String awsRegion = "us-east-1";
    
    protected final String awsRoleArn = "arn:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    
    protected final String awsClientId = "amzn1.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    protected final String awsClientSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    protected final String awsRefreshToken = "Atzr|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" +
            "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" +
            "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" +
            "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    protected final String awsEndpoint = "https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AmzSPAPITest().amazonAwsTest();
    }

    public void amazonAwsTest() {
        try {
            AWSAuthenticationCredentials aac = AWSAuthenticationCredentials.builder()
                    .accessKeyId(awsAccessKeyId)
                    .secretKey(awsSecretAccessKey)
                    .region(awsRegion)
                    .build();

            AWSAuthenticationCredentialsProvider aacp = AWSAuthenticationCredentialsProvider.builder()
                    .roleArn(awsRoleArn)
                    .roleSessionName(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                    .build();

            LWAAuthorizationCredentials lac = LWAAuthorizationCredentials.builder()
                    .clientId(awsClientId)
                    .clientSecret(awsClientSecret)
                    .refreshToken(awsRefreshToken)
                    .endpoint(awsEndpoint)
                    .build();

            SellersApi sa = new SellersApi.Builder()
                    .awsAuthenticationCredentials(aac)
                    .lwaAuthorizationCredentials(lac)
                    .awsAuthenticationCredentialsProvider(aacp)
                    .endpoint("https://sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com")
                    .build();

            GetMarketplaceParticipationsResponse res = sa.getMarketplaceParticipations();
            List<MarketplaceParticipation> data = res.getPayload();
            for (MarketplaceParticipation obj: data) {
                System.out.println(obj);
            }
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
}
```